# jQuery If else applying wrong class in wrong order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a script that looks for a particular class and if that class exists something happens.
For instance if I find the class 'active-01' on the page the script runs for 'active 1' if the class 'active-02' is on a page the script for 'active-02' runs.

My script is

```
if($("*").hasClass("active-01")){
            $(".active-01").addClass("showText").removeClass("active-01");
            $(".showText").css(
                {
                "background":"pink",
                "border":"1px solid red",
                "font-size":"1rem"
                }
            )            
        } else {
            $(".showText").addClass("active-01").removeClass("showText").removeAttr("style");            
        }
        if($("*").hasClass("active-02")){
            $(".active-02").addClass("showText").removeClass("active-02");
            $(".Text").css(
                {
                "background":"pink",
                "border":"1px solid red",
                "font-size":"1rem"
                }
            )            
        } else {
            $(".showText").addClass("active-02").removeClass("showText").removeAttr("style");            
        }
```

The classes 'active-01' and 'active-02' don't appear together on any page.

*The problem is when I run the script on a page that uses the 'active-01' class it does not work as I expected:*

Running the script the first time removes the class 'active-01' (correct) but does not add the class 'showText'. Instead it adds the class 'active-02'.

Running the script the second time I get: 
 (correct).

Running the script the final time the class 'active-01' is inserted, the style attribute is remove and the class'showText is removed' (correct).

This is what is supposed to happen:

Click 1:
If the class 'active-01' exists:
    add the class 'showText'
    remove the class 'active-01'
    add styles for the class 'active-01'.
Click 2:
    add the original class 'active-01' 
    remove the inserted class 'showText'
    remove the attribute style.

I hope I have explained this sufficiently for someone to help me.

Comment: Thank @mohamed-yousef I still get the same issue using .length

Comment: Your problem is that your ifs run back to back. You start out and say if anything has a class of active-01, then change it to showText. Then, you say if nothing has a class of active-02, then turn your showText (which you JUST created via an active-01 class) into active-02. So in one go you take a active-01, turn it into showText, and then into active-02. I can’t offer any help on a fix for this other than to say I would entirely rethink what you’re doing. Let the classes control the style via actual CSS. This code is very convoluted and inefficient. `'*'` is bad practice and slow.

Comment: Can you show us this HTML structure?

Comment: Thanks @Nate still learning. I 'll rethink the logic.

Comment: If you show us the HTML and the goal of the code, we might be able to offer some pointers on how to go about doing what you’re looking for.

Comment: Like @Nate suggests, using * is not a good practice and you retrieve all just to check if each element has a class... should instead use the selector directly and find 5he elements then enter the if only when elements are returned.

Comment: Right. By doing $('*'), you turn literally every node in the HTML into a jQuery object and then loop through all of them to see if any of them have a class of 'active-01'. A better approach would be to just store $('.active-01') into a variable, since this will be a list of only the nodes that have this class. Then, if the .length of this selector is > 0, then you can do your addClass and removeClass to that variable. This is just an example of how to make that aspect more efficient. I still think there’s better approach to all of this somehow, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone. I went and thought about my flawed logic. And thanks to all the suggestions I have a working script.

```
( function( $ ) {
    "use strict";   
    var srt1 = $('.sr-only').length;
    var myDiv1 = document.createElement('div');
        myDiv1.className = "how-many-srts";
        myDiv1.innerHTML = "There are " + srt1 + " possible uses of screen reader only text in use";
          if (document.body){
          document.body.appendChild(myDiv1);
        }
        if(srt1){
            $(".sr-only").addClass("showoffScreenText-01").removeClass("sr-only");
        } else {
            $(".showoffScreenText-01").addClass("sr-only").removeClass("showoffScreenText-01");
            $(".how-many-srts").remove();              
        }
    var srt2 = $(".ui-helper-hidden-accessible").length;
    var myDiv2 = document.createElement('div');
        myDiv2.className = "how-many-srts";
        myDiv2.innerHTML = "There are " + srt2 + " possible uses of screen reader only text in use";
          if (document.body){
          document.body.appendChild(myDiv2);
        }
        if(srt2){
            $(".offscreen").addClass("showoffScreenText-02").removeClass("offscreen");           
        } else {
            $(".showoffScreenText-02").addClass("offscreen").removeClass("showoffScreenText-02");
            $(".how-many-srts").remove();        
        }
    var srt3 = $(".ui-helper-hidden-accessible").length;
    var myDiv3 = document.createElement('div');
        myDiv3.className = "how-many-srts";
        myDiv3.innerHTML = "There are " + srt3 + " possible uses of screen reader only text in use";
          if (document.body){
          document.body.appendChild(myDiv3);
        }
        if(srt3){
            $(".offscreenText").addClass("showoffScreenText-03").removeClass("offscreenText");          
        } else {
            $(".showoffScreenText-03").addClass("offscreen").removeClass("showoffScreenText-03");
            $(".how-many-srts").remove();     
        }
    var srt4 = $(".ui-helper-hidden-accessible").length;
    var myDiv4 = document.createElement('div');
        myDiv4.className = "how-many-srts";
        myDiv4.innerHTML = "There are " + srt4 + " possible uses of screen reader only text in use";
          if (document.body){
          document.body.appendChild(myDiv4);
        }
        if(srt4){
            $(".ui-helper-hidden-accessible").addClass("showoffScreenText-04").removeClass("ui-helper-hidden-accessible");        
        } else {
            $(".showoffScreenText-04").addClass("ui-helper-hidden-accessible").removeClass("showoffScreenText-04");
            $(".how-many-srts").remove();  
        }
    var srt5 = $('.ms-accessible').length;
    var myDiv5 = document.createElement('div');
        myDiv5.className = "how-many-srts";
        myDiv5.innerHTML = "There are " + srt5 + " possible uses of screen reader only text in use";
          if (document.body){
          document.body.appendChild(myDiv5);
        }
        if(srt5){
            $(".ms-accessible").addClass("showoffScreenText-05").removeClass("ms-accessible");           
        } else {
            $(".showoffScreenText-05").addClass("ms-accessible").removeClass("showoffScreenText-05");
            $(".how-many-srts").remove();           
        }
    var srt6 = $('.off-screen').length;
    var myDiv6 = document.createElement('div');
        myDiv6.className = "how-many-srts";
        myDiv6.innerHTML = "There are " + srt6 + " possible uses of screen reader only text in use";
          if (document.body){
          document.body.appendChild(myDiv6);
        }
        if(srt6){
            $(".off-screen").addClass("showoffScreenText-06").removeClass("off-screen");           
        } else {
            $(".showoffScreenText-06").addClass("off-screen").removeClass("showoffScreenText-06");
            $(".how-many-srts").remove();          
        }
    var srt7 = $('.accessibility').length;
    var myDiv7 = document.createElement('div');
        myDiv7.className = "how-many-srts";
        myDiv7.innerHTML = "There are " + srt7 + " possible uses of screen reader only text in use";
          if (document.body){
          document.body.appendChild(myDiv7);
        }
        if(srt7){
            $(".accessibility").addClass("showoffScreenText-07").removeClass("accessibility");           
        } else {
            $(".showoffScreenText-07").addClass("accessibility").removeClass("showoffScreenText-07");
            $(".how-many-srts").remove();          
        }
    var srt8 = $('.accessible-module-heading').length;
    var myDiv8 = document.createElement('div');
        myDiv8.className = "how-many-srts";
        myDiv8.innerHTML = "There are " + srt8 + " possible uses of screen reader only text in use";
          if (document.body){
          document.body.appendChild(myDiv8);
        }
        if(srt8){
            $(".accessible-module-heading").addClass("showoffScreenText-08").removeClass("accessible-module-heading");           
        } else {
            $(".showoffScreenText-08").addClass("accessible-module-heading").removeClass("showoffScreenText-08");
            $(".how-many-srts").remove();         
        }
} )( jQuery );
```

Okay I know I can improve this and eventually would really like to code it in JavaScript (not jQuery). However, for now that is beyond my skill set.

In case anyone is interested in Accessibility the purpose behind this is an experimental extension that visually displays off-screen text developers sometimes include.
Please remember this is an idea and is experimental

Chrome extension
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/show-screen-reader-text/fbfkajlfifmdaaagijbanghjmleigkee

Firefox extension
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/show-screen-reader-text/

A website that show this working:

The Australian ABC TV web page
https://www.abc.net.au/tv/

Answer (score 0):

> Running the script the first time removes the class 'active-01' (correct) but **does not add the class 'showText'**. Instead it adds the class 'active-02'.

Yes it does.

The main body of your first if statement runs because there is an element with class `active-01`. It removes that class, and replaces it with `showText`. Then, immediately after, your second if statement gets checked. That condition is false, so the body of its else block runs, which removes `showText` and adds `active-02`.

It might be easier to follow if you clean up the indenting a little bit:

```
if ($("*").hasClass("active-01")) {
    // This part runs
    $(".active-01").addClass("showText").removeClass("active-01");
    $(".showText").css({
        "background": "pink",
        "border": "1px solid red",
        "font-size": "1rem"
    })
} else {
    // This doesn't run
    $(".showText").addClass("active-01").removeClass("showText").removeAttr("style");
}
if ($("*").hasClass("active-02")) {
    // This doesn't run
    $(".active-02").addClass("showText").removeClass("active-02");
    $(".Text").css({
        "background": "pink",
        "border": "1px solid red",
        "font-size": "1rem"
    })
} else {
    // This part runs
    $(".showText").addClass("active-02").removeClass("showText").removeAttr("style");
}
```